# Putting Card in Center of The Page in React

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, jss

I have a simple problem putting just the card to the center of the page. I've already put `alignItems: center` and `justifyContent: center` but it still not displaying on the center page.

Check this codesandbox link [CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-hwo7f?file=/demo.js:393-669)

**CODE**

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  root: {
    minWidth: 275,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  cardHeader: {
    backgroundColor: "blue",
    color: "white",
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  }
}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flex on parent, note that you need to set `height` so it will center accordingly.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    height: "100vh"
  },
  cardHeader: {/*...*/}
}));
```

[image: Edit Material demo]

Comment: Can you explain why the height is `100vh`? what does it mean? Can be `100+...`. Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units, `1vh` = 1% of the viewport's height. It just means "take all screen", you can use any `height` you like, its just an example, you must add height otherwise will take the default value: `auto`

Comment: I tried in my app, there's scrollbar appearing when i set height to `100vh`. What's the ideal height for it? Thanks

Comment: There is no such thing ideal, it depends, `100%` might work...